# Generate jSon file

Tags: json, file

How to generate jSon file via PHP?

I have seen jSon files over 4mb and more.

I think tt's very good practice to keep such big data cached than taken from database everytime.

And update it one a week or a day.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JSON facilities](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) can be used to read and write JSON.

Comment: So we encode data into jSon format and then by using fopen and fwrite functions , creating .json file?